# The Cut & Paste HTML5 Mouseover/ Click sound effect script

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script posted on this site: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/...oundlink.shtml

It works great, but I want to extend this script and mute the sound using a checkbox. This checkbox has the id: sound. If checked, I want to hear the sounds, when unchecked, no sounds should be heard.

This is the code I currently have for the checkbox:
Code:

```
function playSound() {
    if (document.getElementById('sound').checked){
        -something needs to be added here to make it work?-
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function muteIt(box) {
if (clicksound){
  clicksound.muted = box.checked?true:false;
    }
 if (mouseoversound){
 mouseoversound.muted = box.checked?true:false;
    } 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
// Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for full source code

//** Usage: Instantiate script by calling: var uniquevar=createsoundbite("soundfile1", "fallbackfile2", "fallebacksound3", etc)
//** Call: uniquevar.playclip() to play sound   

var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
"wav": "audio/wav"
}

function createsoundbite(sound){
    var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
    if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
            sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
            html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
        }
        html5audio.load()
        html5audio.playclip=function(){
                    if (document.getElementById('sound').checked){

                html5audio.pause()
                    html5audio.currentTime=0
                    html5audio.play()

                    }
        }
    return html5audio
}
else{
    return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support    HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
}
}

//Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

var mouseoversound=createsoundbite("whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
var clicksound=createsoundbite("click.ogg", "click.mp3")

</script>
```

So, it'll check if the box is checked. If it is, then it'll play. If not, then it will not play.